# Has the small object allocator found in "Modern C++ Design"/Loki been deprecated in favor of newer implementations?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, boost, c++-loki

It seems the code and the book have been relegated to the foundation of the movement of modern C++, and isn't updated any more. Is there some kind of replacement for this in Boost or TR1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/pool/doc/index.html) library.